# Count KeyPresses of defined Keys on JavaScript - Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I work on a website that has buttons that trigger actions to verify media.

Eight of those buttons are definitive actions that finish the process of verification.

To count how many verifications per day, I've been using this extension: [Button Counter G - Chrome Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/button-counter-g/lfgnadfkaiepombekpbccllpbkiealal) with the Target Selector set to: `._3ecQ715A_pJG8wssLJzBkX > button`

It does the work well, except for counting three other buttons that don't end the verification process.

And, the worst part, it just works if the buttons are clicked with the mouse.

But, all those eight buttons are assigned to Key shortcuts, which are `1` `2` `3` `4` `5` `6` `7` `8`.

I wonder if there is a way to create a TamperMonkey script that is a COUNTER for those 8 buttons/keys.

It should display somewhere on the browser the number of times I've pressed the keys `1` `2` `3` `4` `5` `6` `7` `8` while using the domain "exampleworkwebsite.com"

Also, it should store the information until I manually reset it. And, it should count not in only one URL or Tab, but all the URLs and Open Tabs similar to this: `https://exampleworkwebsite.com/lists/*`

Any help or idea is appreciated.

I even thought about setting this script as a Chrome Extension, but I never did it and didn't know how to do it.